# How can I expose a StatefulWidget's method?

Tags: dart, flutter

Say I want to build a StatefulWidget named `MySlideWidget` that provides a public instance method: `animate()`.

When I press a button on parent of `MySlideWidget`, then I can call `MySlideWidget`'s `animate()` method to trigger an internal `SlideTransition` of `MySlideWidget`.

The usage would look like this:

```
class MySlideWidgetDemo extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MySlideWidget mySlideWidget = new MySlideWidget();

    return new Scaffold(
        body: mySlideWidget,
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            mySlideWidget.animate();
          },
          tooltip: 'Start',
          child: new Icon(Icons.add),
        ));
  }
}
```

What I wondering is how to encapsulate the implementations of `AnimationController` and `_controller.forward()` inside `MySlideWidget`, so user of `MySlideWidget` can simply call `animate()`.

Is this possible? Or what is the idea way to do encapsulation in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [AnimationController](https://flutter.io/animations/#animationcontroller) and pass it to `SlideTransition`. Then call `controller.forward()` when needed.

Here is sample:

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<FractionalOffset> _slideTransitionPosition;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
    );

    _slideTransitionPosition = new FractionalOffsetTween(
      begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, -1.0),
      end: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 10.0),
    ).animate(new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    ));
  }

  void _onPress() {
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        child: new SlideTransition(
          position: _slideTransitionPosition,
          child: new Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: 100.0,
            height: 100.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _onPress,
        tooltip: 'Start',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also you can find examples in [demos](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/60f5ae8e77ecfd479333ce68a8fd81b0778132f1/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/drawer_demo.dart#L31)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated my question to describe more accurately. Briefly speaking here, I am wondering how to encapsulate animation implementations inside a StatefulWidget.

Comment: I got it. In this case, you can use as a reference implementation of `Form` and `FormState` [src](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/c7469e005d2def9bc1759cfbb39b75f293eac561/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/form.dart#L20) . It's StatefulWidget and its State that exposes method `save`. So you need to get right instance of state and trigger animation there.